# Change class name on page scroll

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to make a java script call that changes the class name of my navigation.

My navigation is like this when the page first loads:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="topNav">
```

I want to change it to the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topNav">
```

My javascript is the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $('#topNav').className('navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top');
});
```

I want this event to happen as soon as the page scrolls past the very top. if the page is scrolled back to the top I want it to go back to original. Currently when I scroll, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the current scroll position with

```
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
```

If `scrollPosition` is `0`, it means that you are on the very top. If it is greater than `0`, it means that the user has scrolled downwards.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
        // We are at the top of the page and want to remove the class
        $('#topNav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
        $('#topNav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
});
```

This code removes the class `navbar-fixed-top` from the navbar as soon as the user has scrolled to the top and adds the class to the navbar as soon as the user scrolls away from the top.

Assuming that you CSS looks something like this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

you can create cool effects when you add the class `navbar-fixed-top` only for values of `scrollPosition > 200` or so.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TnTRE/1/